# How do I tell a user where the line error occurred?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to incorporate enumerate so I can give the user of the program where the line error was and the input of that line.

Here is my code:

```
elif response == 'data2':
    print('Processing file:', response + '.txt')
    try:
        infile = open('data2.txt', 'r')
        for line in infile:
            amount = float(line)
            total += amount
        infile.close()
        print(format(total, ',.2f'))

    except IOError:
        print("IO Error occurred trying to read the file.")
    except ValueError:
        print("Non-numeric data found in file:", response + '.txt')
    except:
        print("An error occurred.")
```

As you see I want the `ValueError`to output something along the lines of:

> Non-numeric data found in file: data2.txt at line: 3 with input: three
>   hundred

I'm however stuck on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#enumerate) built-in function to get the line number:

```
elif response == 'data2':
    print('Processing file:', response + '.txt')
    try:
        # Python allows you to iterate over a file object directly.
        for line_no, line in enumerate(open('data2.txt', 'r')):
            amount = float(line)
            total += amount
        print(format(total, ',.2f'))
    except IOError:
        print("IO Error occurred trying to read the file.")
    except ValueError:
        # I took the liberaty of formatting your output in a way
        # that's a bit more readble than one long line of text.
        print("Non-numeric data found in file: {}.txt at line: {}"
              "with input: {}".format(response, line_no + 1, line))
    except:
        print("An error occurred.")
```

Comment: So I tried giving this a go however it's outputting an improper line number - 2 instead of 3. Also input is showing 300.0 so I'm assuming it's totaling lines 1 (100.0) and line 2 (200.0) instead of showing line 3 (three hundred)

Comment: @Nite, `line_no` is zero based (0 for first line, 1 for 2nd) so just add one if you want it to start at one. You probably want `.format(response, line_no, line)` (instead of `total`) to print the current line in the error

Comment: @Nite Yeah, thanks Peter. Forgot to change that back when I modified my code.

Comment: @Nite Yes, I forgot to mention that `line_no` is zero based. Meaning that is starts counting at one. A simple fix is to just add one to `line_no` when outputting it - like in my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to track what line you are up to in the file, and catch the exception while reading.

```
for line_number, line in enumerate(infile, 1):
    try:
        amount = float(line)
    except ValueError:
        print(
            "Non-numeric data found in file",
            response + ".txt on line",
            line_number,
            "with input",
            line
        )
        exit(1)  # or whatever is appropriate for this script.
```